# How to load a file in Shiny only once?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm just wondering how to run read.csv in server.R only once? In the following code, each time that I change the input in ui.R, it takes a few seconds for the code to run read.csv, therefore I'm looking forward to load the file only once at the beginning then use the same data when input in ui.R changes. Thanks
Here is my code:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
     headerPanel("myApp"),
     fluidRow(   sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("myOptions", "myOptions:",
                list("1" = "1", 
                     "2" = "2",
                     "3" = "3"))
     )),
     hr(),
     plotlyOutput("prescription"),   
     hr()   
      ))
```

server.R

```
library(utils)
library(plotly)
library(plyr)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  diseases<-eventReactive({
    diseases=read.csv("diseases_94.csv",header=F)
 })


  output$prescription <- renderPlotly( {

   myDiseases=diseases
   freq=count(myDiseases,"DISEASES")

   p<-plot_ly(freq, labels = ~DISEASES, values = ~freq, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'inside',
        textinfo = 'label+percent',
        insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~paste(DISEASES),
        marker = list(line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)))



 p


 })


 })
```

Comment: If you only want to load it once, why could just load it outside the server function? Maybe you could tell us more when and how you want to read in the data,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist thanks for your response. I need to load only at the beginning when I run the shiny app. Should I then pass it to the shinyServer function as an input parameter?

Comment: you could just use it like a normal variable,..

Comment: @BigDataScientist Got it! it's working now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Use the variable outside of `shinyServer`. This should load the file only in the beginning.